# Get ancestor or self with class

Tags: jquery

I need to get the ancestor or current element depending if it has a class.

Below is a jsfiddle of the a section of html. It is basically an a container div with inner elements. The container is repeated on the page. What I need to do is find out if the mouse element that the HTML dragenter event is fired on is contained within the container and if so set the class of the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/EKmKT/

How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean getting an ancestor if the element has a certain class or self otherwise?

Comment: Just edited question hopefully it is clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `closest` method which gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

I think this will suit the best based on your requirement.

E.g: Consider this markup

```
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
//will get the same element because the selector matches with .class1
$('.class1').closest('.class1');

//will get the parent element with class2
$('.class1').closest('.class2');
```

Answer (score 2):

Gets the first element matching `.className` as the DOM is traversed upwards from the current element:

```
$(this).closest('.className');
```

- [closest()<sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

if it has a class:

`$('.class')` will give you the element.

`$('.class').parent()` gets the ancestor.

very basic stuff  http://docs.jquery.com

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I really want a function that will perform similar to XSLT's ancestor-or-self